# Write the Laplacian operator in a particular coordinate system

Tags: analysis, laplacian

I have to write the differential operator the Laplacian, divergence, gradient in the following curvilinear coordinate system:
$$\left \{ \begin{array}{rl}
x=(R_0+r\cos\theta )\cos\phi\\
y=(R_0+r\cos\theta )\sin\phi \\
z=r\sin\theta
\end{array}
\right.$$
with $R_0>0$.
I managed to find $$ds^2=dr^2+r^2d\theta^2+(R_0+r\cos\theta)^2 d\phi^2$$  for the determination of the factors $h_1,h_2, h_3$ to put inside the general formula for an orthogonal curvilinear coordinate system. Is it correct?
Any help?